# Include the java -version command in bash script

Tags: java, linux, shell

[Message updated to include script and its output as you asked].

I have created a linux script which installs Oracle Java on Ubuntu.

The script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script installs Oracle Java 7u51 jdk on Ubuntu Linux 64 bit

echo "Starting Oracle Java JDK Installation..."
sudo mkdir /usr/local/java
cd
sudo cp -r jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/java
rm jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz
cd /usr/local/java

echo "Unpacking java files in /usr/local/java"
sudo tar xvzf jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo rm jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz
sleep 1s

echo "Updating system Path file /etc/profile with Java variables"
sudo sed -i '$ a\JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51' /etc/profile
sudo sed -i '$ a\PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin' /etc/profile
sudo sed -i '$ a\export JAVA_HOME' /etc/profile
sudo sed -i '$ a\export PATH' /etc/profile
sleep 1s

echo "Updating alternatives"
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/
jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/
jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/
jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javaws" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javaws
sleep 3s

echo "Reload system wide Path /etc/profile"
. /etc/profile
sleep 3s

echo "Testing if Java is installed correctly. System must reply with Java version."
java –version
sleep 1s
javac -version
```

The script runs fine doing its thing and Java is installed correctly.
But the java -version command at the end gives this output at the terminal.

**Testing if Java is installed correctly. System must reply with Java version.**

Error: Could not find or load main class –version

javac 1.7.0_51

Two things baffle me.
The first is that the javac -version commands works in the script but not the java -version command.

The second is that if I go to the terminal right after the script has ended and input myself java -version, it works.

Comment: By "it does not work", do you mean that you get an exception or that it doesn't output anything? Also, if you create a test bash script which ONLY calls `java -version`, does that work? Adding both of those data points may help you get better traction on feedback.

Comment: PS: Proof-of-concept is that it *should* work from within a bash script. I just created a two-line script consisting of `#!/bin/bash` and `java -version`, and it works fine.

Comment: @concept303 Yes, I believe what DreadPirateShawn said is the right way to do this - try to see if this works with the most simple setup possible.  If it does not, paste the code you are using here, and an example of the command running fine outside the script (that is, directly in your terminal).

Comment: I think pasting your script code will be helpful that others can find the reason.

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn: Tried it, still same result. Does not work from script, works from terminal with me inputting command manually. This persists after a reboot.

Comment: Please show the smallest script which reproduces this problem. You confirmed that the issue reproduces with a two-liner script, so show only that. Both the script and the output for `java -version` and for `sh -c java -version` -- that way we can copy and paste your exact (small!) script and help more easily. (Given the down-votes due to the cruft in this particular question, you may need to file a fresh question, keeping it cleaner.)

Answer (score 3):

The install may be adding to the PATH, which you won't see from inside the current shell. Try it with

```
sh -c java -version
```

Comment: Did what you said, no go. I am updating the main message to include the script, so please look there if you have any other idea. Thank you

Comment: There is no evidence above that you did what I said.

Comment: I know but I did try it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can change the calling order, you can call the reload system wide Path operation before the update-alternatives operations.